# Use a custom block in another block

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor

Let's assume that I have a music player block and it's working fine.
I now want to add another block for playlists and I want to use this single player block in this block.
Is it possible to import this block into my playlist or should I just create a duplicate of all files in my playlist block?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create custom blocks with `InnerBlocks`. If you only want the parent block to include music player blocks, you can define that in `ALLOWED_BLOCKS`. https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/

Comment: Actually, I don't want the users to be able to use the single player in the album player. I want to just use it in code. So when a user selects 3 music, it automatically creates an album player with this single player.